# PDE with quasi-Legendre ODE on RHS

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have a PDE I'm trying to solve

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}(z,x) = A\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(x(x-1)\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}(z,x)\bigg), \quad x > 1,$$
where $A$ is a constant. The RHS of the PDE looks very similar to a [Legendre differential equation.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDifferentialEquation.html)

The right hand side can be written as
$$A\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg((x^2-1)\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\bigg)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg((1-x)\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\bigg)\bigg),$$
the first of which being a legendre differential equation. However it's not in quite the right form. I'm looking for some advice how to solve this, thanks.

Comment: If you let $z = t$, you might recognise the PDE as an [advection-diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation) with non-constant coefficients.

Comment: Interesting. Might superposition apply when trying to solve this equation?